# Set of values of $i^{i^i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to find all the set of values for the expression $i^{i^i}$.

For the principal value of this expression I got $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}$, please correct me if wrong.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe the principal value would actually be $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\pi/2}}=0.947+0.321i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact $i=e^{\ln i}$ and $\ln i=i\frac{\pi}{2}+i(2\pi n) \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$ . Can you go from gere$?$

Comment: Well, but I get 2 parameters $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. One for each of the powers. I guess I have to define 2 parameters $n,n’$ and define the set of values in terms of that, right?

Comment: @PhilMett That's correct. There are two multivalued operations so there's two sets of integers indexing the set of values.